# Searching SQL data using Spark

Tags: search, apache-spark, pyspark

I am creating the spark job that searchs records (SQL rows) relevant to a keyword using tf-idf model. What I am currently doing for testing is to spark-submit the job to get results. However, ideally I want to make this job as a web service so that external users can search records using REST API. This may generate a number of concurrent requests to run the job for multiple users when they search own keywords through the API.

I wonder if I should support this scenario with spark job server so that users can submit jobs via API, or if you have any suggestion for this particular case based on your past experience. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be an inappropriate use of Spark. Spark is for analytics jobs. Those take time (maybe less time than old-school MapReduce but time nonetheless), and REST clients demand immediate results.

You are on the right track though. As data come in, you can use, for example, Spark Streaming and MLLib to process records according to your TD-IDF and then store the indexed results in your SQL database. Then your REST clients will simply query your data like with all the conventional web-with-SQL-backend applications our ancestors once built.

I suppose you could also look into giving admins the ability to start analytics jobs via a REST client too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess I can start from manually creating indexed results in spark and then querying it locally. In terms of the indexed results, do you mean vector representation of words with frequency such as HasingTF? What do you think about saving tf-idf model itself i.e. tfidf.saveAsTextFile("/tfidf") and parse it for finding relevant records?

Comment: More generally, your indexes should contain the data you expect your REST clients to query for--stored in a way that optimizes those queries. As for using HDFS, don't do it. Store the data in a database optimized for fast reads.

Comment: Okay. I might store the indexes in some new database since storing in SQL might impose conversion (or parsing) cost of indexes when storing and retrieving them, as they are likely to be collection. This may impact fast reads of search too. Thanks.

Comment: Cassandra or Mongo or really any of the leading document-based stores would be good for that then. Also, please report back and comment here and accept this answer *or* add your own better answer and accept that so others can learn from your experience in the future.

Comment: I have marked your answer as the best answer :) I might try save it as parquet format in local (or hdfs) system, then comparing it with when I use document-based storage like MongoDB as a learning opportunity. It was great that I can get help from you!

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project!